# OutOfMemory exception creating a large zip file

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am attempting to create a zip file using the `Ionic.Zip` library in .NET. My procedure iterates over a list of files from various sources and puts each file (file bytes, file name) into the zip file my procedure builds (as shown below).

The procedure below works great for smaller lists of files. But with larger lists of files, my procedure throws an `OutOfMemory` exception. I "thought" I was putting the zipped contents directly into the zip file I am building. But since I am getting an `OutOfMemory` exception, it makes me think that my procedure is loading up everything into memory before saving it to disk.

This is my procedure:

```
using (var tempFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(tempFileStream))
{
    foreach (var fileRec in dbFileRecs)
    {
        var fileToPutInZip = getFileData();

        if (fileToPutInZip != null)
        {
            var fileNameToDownload = removeIllegalChars(fileToPutInZip.FileName);
            fileNameToDownload = ensureUniqueFilename(fileNameToDownload);
            var entry = zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(fileNameToDownload);

            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileToPutInZip.FileData)) // FileData is a byte array
            {
                ms.CopyTo(zipOutputStream);
            }

            zipOutputStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    zipOutputStream.Flush();
    zipOutputStream.Close();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I write directly to the zip file and not load up the whole file into memory (and avoid those `OutOfMemory` errors)?

Comment: Change `fileToPutInZip.FileData` from a byte array to a Stream, and use Stream.CopyTo() when you want to write the data to the `zipOutputStream`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWilliamson. I'll give that a shot. But, don't I already have that FileData wrapped in a memory string ` using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileToPutInZip.FileData)) `?

Comment: I'm asssuming the data type of `FileData` is a byte array here. The problem is that you have to load the whole file (or web request or wherever it's coming from) into the array, which is held in memory. This happens before you get to `MemoryStream`. The memory stream is wrapping your array, so yes it's a stream, but the contents of the entire stream are already in memory. If you keep `FileData` as a stream the whole way, you give yourself the option of using a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream`, so it only loads bytes from the file on demand

Comment: I see. Yes, `FileData` is a byte array. The problem I have is that FileData comes from many different kinds of external sources. Most of them are cloud services such as AWS storage, HTTP web clients, etc. I think I would have an even larger problem if I try to keep those as streams, wouldn't I? I would have to keep all those connections open (I think). There are around 10,000 "files" (with `FileData`) that are all downloaded one at a time in the `getFileData()` function. What if I saved each of those 10,000 byte arrays to temporary files, and got a stream to each file?

Comment: You could make a `IStreamProvider` interface, with an implementation per cloud service e.g. `AwsStreamProvider`, which knows how to open the stream when it is needed. Or you could just put them all in temp files, that would definitely be the easiest option

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWilliamson. Creating a `IStreamProvider` is really going to be problematic, as there are multiple types of data sources (around 15 different types) I would have to accomodate and write this provider for. Plus, there are other complexities to be handled, such as tokens refreshing, etc. However, I attempted saving each one as it's own temp file, and I believe that worked!